# SQL regroup all dates in one (Century) like date format

Tags: mysql, sql, date

So I want to regroup all the dates that I have in only one date, so that in the end I have only one row.

Let's say I want to regroup the dates by 100 years.

something like `date_format(myDate,'%Y')` but for every 100 years.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: My French is lousy, but I think Millénaire translates as Millennium, whereas 100 years is merely a Century (Siècle)

Comment: @Strawberry well your frech is better than mine, I thought mean Millions :/.

Comment: Yup that was a mistake guys thanks for noticing that ;)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza My Frech is even worse than my French!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use integer division `DIV`

- `{0-99} DIV 100 = 0`
- `{100-199} DIV 100 = 1`

.

```
SELECT date_format(myDate,'%Y') DIV 100, count(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date_format(myDate,'%Y') DIV 100
```